# enable track pad tapping in awesome wm

Tags: mouse, awesome-wm

I use Ubuntu 19.10 with awesome 4.3. On the gnome5 desktop., the mouse works like expected but switching to awesome disables the tapping functionality. Right and left click on the bottom corners of my Lenovo T460s works and I can move the mouse pointer and two finger scrolling. Just tapping does not work. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tapping and other touchpad settings are configured either through XInput2 as "device properties", or through Xorg.conf as settings for the 'libinput' driver.

You can run this command on login (as part of Awesomewm startup, or as part of your ~/.xinitrc):

```
xinput set-prop "$touchpad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1
```

Replace `$touchpad` with the device name (*not* ID number) that you see in `xinput list`.

Alternatively, create /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-touchpad-settings.conf with contents such as (I'm not sure if I got the syntax right):

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Touchpads"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
EndSection
```

See [libinput(4)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/xserver-xorg-input-libinput/libinput.4.en.html) for more details.

Comment: thank you sir. the second option worked

Comment: do you also happen to know how I can invert the two-finger scrolling behaviour? An u gesture should scroll down but is instead scrolling up...

Comment: Look for the option called "Natural scrolling".

Comment: where is this option to be found?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput `Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"`

Comment: thanks a lot. One last question: can I also specify that suspend should kick it when the lid is closed?

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment on the accepted answer I'll leave complementary answer.

Here's a way of making this more generic that should probably work on most devices:

```
xinput set-prop "$(xinput list --name-only | grep -i touch)" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1
```

`xinput list --name-only` returns names only, avoiding annoying `⎜   ↳` characters, and `grep -i touch` filters for 'touch' ignoring case.